# Web application to convert Excel files to PDF (Separate PDF for each worksheet)

Tags: web-apps, pdf, document-converter, microsoft-excel, file-converter

Is there any web application to convert an Excel file with multiple sheets to PDF files? Each sheet will be created as a new PDF file.

If I have 3 worksheets in Excel, I'll have 3 PDFs after conversion.

> Sheet1 > Sheet1.pdf
>
> Sheet2 > Sheet2.pdf
>
> Sheet3 > Sheet3.pdf

Comment: Do you need it done automatically for all sheets, or can it be manually for one worksheet at a time?

Comment: Need a tool to do it automatically. Only input is Excel file. User will click a button and It will create output files.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion Excel to PDF converter will be able to convert Excel sheets into separate PDF documents. The default implementation of the converter can be tested here:

http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/xlsio/exceltopdf.aspx

Since this is a library, it can be customized to create one PDF per sheet instead of the single PDF the above web application produces.

Regards,

Davis

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the convert method of LibreOffice that you can call from a script so it can be automatized. I can not tell you by heart all the filtering options for excel files. We use LibreOffice for PDF conversion in our library that is a web app. You may even write your own macros that would let you do whatever you need but we only work with .odt and .doc so I can not say much about excel or calc.

Comment: Is that a ***web application***, as requested? How does it meet the other requirements (separate PDF files for each worksheet)?

Comment: I can not tell you by heart all the filtering options for excel files. We use LibreOffice for PDF conversion in our library [link](http://www.html52pdf.com) that is a web app. You may even write your own macros that would let you do whatever you need but we only work with .odt and .doc so I can not say much about excel or calc.

Comment: That should go to your answer :) Not only are one-liners frowned upon – here at SR we have [very specific quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to stick to.